# Angular2 show this error: TypeError: Object has no method 'requestAnimationFrame'

Tags: cordova, angular

I am building an app with phonegap + angular2 and on older browsers (stock browser on Samsung S3 for example) I am getting this error:

```
[phonegap] [console.error] ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'requestAnimationFrame'
[phonegap] [console.error] ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
[phonegap] [console.error] TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'requestAnimationFrame'
[phonegap]     at BrowserDomAdapter.requestAnimationFrame (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30516:94)
[phonegap]     at RafQueue._raf (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30048:32)
[phonegap]     at new RafQueue (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30043:15)
[phonegap]     at BrowserDetails.raf (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30029:22)
[phonegap]     at BrowserDetails.doesElapsedTimeIncludesDelay (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30018:15)
[phonegap]     at new BrowserDetails (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:30007:15)
[phonegap]     at http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:4871:46
[phonegap]     at Injector._instantiate (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:3359:28)
[phonegap]     at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:3300:26)
[phonegap]     at Injector._new (http://10.10.255.247:3000/libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js:3289:22)
```

[Html5test.com](http://Html5test.com) give the browser a score of: `228 points`
And does not have support for `window.requestAnimationFrame`

I include this scrips:

```
<script src="libs/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>
```

I don't use any animation. What can I do to be able to run angular2 in older browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to load the js: `https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.12/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js` It's not only for ie. For old Android browsers too.

This file can be found in 5 min example.

Comment: As of `angular-2.0.0-rc.1` I can't find the shims any more and they are no longer in the tutorial. What's the proposed solution for this now?

Comment: @MartinC. I didn't upgrade to rc.1 yet. I am with beta 14. Hope I will have time soon to upgrade and fix all the conflicts and to see how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of polyfills, maybe some I don't need, but in them I found this function:

```
//RequestAnimationFrame (IE9, Android 4.1, 4.2, 4.3)
/*! @author Paul Irish */
/*! @source https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671 */
// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel

// MIT license

(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = Date.now();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
```

I don't remember where I originally found the snippet, but I needed this for an older version of IE. It should also work for you.

Comment: This is still a working workaround for `angular-2.0.0-rc.1` and Android 4.3